# HTML5 and HTML5 mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

Is there any different between

```
 html5
```

and

```
 css3
```

in mobile version development? Different template?

Comment: They are different languages for a start. This is like asking is there any difference between cars and bread - both useful, but quite different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 is the same for mobile technology. HTML and CSS are the same for Desktop or Mobile browsers. It's just that you can use specific features for mobile:

`In mobile devices, HTML5 is often used for mobile websites and mobile applications on Mobile operating systems such as Firefox OS, Sailfish OS, Tizen, and Ubuntu Touch. It provides developers with tools such as Offline Web Storage, GeoLocation API, Canvas Drawing, CSS3, and many more.After observing the trend of mobile game app in the market, various people have started looking for the finest approach in game application development that can reach maximum users, is cost-effective and gives the best user-experience.`

from Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_in_mobile_devices

Answer (score 0):

Well! they are entirely different langs.HTML5 is used for building markups or creating the skeleton of a webpage and CSS3 is used for styling webpages, they both are the latest versions of their categories {HTML(5) / CSS(3)}. As far as your question goes in mobile development they both play their parts.

learn more about them from here- https://www.w3schools.com/css/ & https://www.w3schools.com/html/